# Importing Vue npm module into my javascript file

Tags: npm, vue.js

What is the proper way to import VueJs into my javascript file using NPM? I am getting a Vue is not defined error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [install the package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally):

```
$ npm install vue
```

And then import it in whatever file you want to use Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will accept this answer as soon as Stack Overflow allows me. @thanksd